# Non working ArXive file

Tags: xetex, errors, winedt, compilation-error

I have un-tarred an interesting book from [here](https://arxiv.org/format/2002.06055) but when trying to compile the file "2categories_book.tex" the following error occurs :
And after pressing enter even more errors occur! How can I fix it ?

```
Command Line:   xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "2categories_book.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 20.6.29)
entering extended mode
(2categories_book.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18>
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/amscls\amsbook.cls
Document Class: amsbook 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/tex-gyre\tgpagella.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/psnfss\mathpazo.sty) (sty/Packages.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/graphics-def\xetex.def)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/leftidx\leftidx.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/mnsymbol\MnSymbol.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/bbm\bbm.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/amsfonts\eucal.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/enumitem\enumitem.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/mathtools\mathtools.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/tools\calc.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/mathtools\mhsetup.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/imakeidx\imakeidx.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/iftex\ifxetex.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/tools\multicol.sty))
Writing index file 2categories_book.idx
) (sty/TikzSetup.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/ms\everyshi.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.cfg)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-xetex.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def))))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.co
de.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.
tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmeti
cs.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/qpl/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 926.

)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.code.t
ex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code.te
x)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations.code
.tex) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex
) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.code.
tex) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.code.te
x) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty))
 (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\tikz.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.code.
tex) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
rytopaths.code.tex))) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/tikz-cd\tikz-cd.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/tikz-cd\tikzlibrarycd.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
rymatrix.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
ryquotes.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.t
ex))) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/pgfplots\pgfplots.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.revision.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotscore.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/sys\pgfplotssysgeneric.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/libs\pgfplotslibrary.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib\pgfplotsoldpgfsupp
_loader.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryfpu.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotsutil.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure\pgfplotsliststructu
re.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure\pgfplotsliststructu
reext.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure\pgfplotsarray.code.
tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure\pgfplotsmatrix.code
.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable\pgfplotstableshared.code
.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure\pgfplotsdeque.code.
tex) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotsbinary.code.tex

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotsbinary.data.code.tex
))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotsutil.verb.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/libs\pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshadi
ng.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/sys\pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshadin
g.pgfsys-xetex.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/sys\pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshadin
g.pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def))))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotscolormap.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotscolor.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsstackedplots.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsmeshplotimage.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.scaling.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotscoordprocessing.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.errorbars.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.markers.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsticks.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.paths.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
rydecorations.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduledecorations.code.tex)
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
rydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations\pgflibrarydecora
tions.pathmorphing.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
rydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations\pgflibrarydecora
tions.pathreplacing.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
ryplotmarks.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex
)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
ryarrows.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryarrows.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
rybackgrounds.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
rypositioning.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
ryfit.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
rypetri.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
ryshapes.misc.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes\pgflibraryshapes.misc
.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
ryshapes.geometric.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes\pgflibraryshapes.geom
etric.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
rydecorations.markings.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations\pgflibrarydecora
tions.markings.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
rycalc.code.tex)) (sty/DefinitionsDY.sty) (sty/Alphabets.sty)
(sty/DefinitionsNJ.sty) (sty/PageSetup.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/oberdiek\stackrel.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/oberdiek\ifdraft.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/generic/iftex\ifpdf.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/datetime\datetime.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/fmtcount\fmtcount.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/fmtcount\fcprefix.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/fmtcount\fcnumparser.sty)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/datetime\datetime-defaults.sty))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.63 \expandafter\parsepdfdatetime\pdfcreationdate
                                                  \endparsepdfdatetime
? 

! Emergency stop.
l.63 \expandafter\parsepdfdatetime\pdfcreationdate
                                                  \endparsepdfdatetime


_____________________________________________________________________

 XeLaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 2   Warnings: 2   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Kind of the same problem as here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/575799/134574. In XeTeX, `\pdfcreationdate` is called `\creationdate`.

Comment: Right now I'd say "Use `pdftex`" answers the question. Is it enough or do you want to make it work with `xetex`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I have succeeded  to compile it with **LaTeX** in WInEdt but WinEdt has created a `2categories_book.dvi` **but I need a `2categories_book.pdf` file. How can I fix this (at best not manually) ?

Comment: use `pdflatex` not `latex`

Comment: @daleif I works fine, **but** it takes 3 minutes to compile the entire `.pdf`. Any hack to make it faster ?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik A similar 600 page long book by Shelah took just 5 seconds.

Comment: @user2925716 Yes, but it's 500 pages _filled_ with TikZ pictures, which do take some time to process.  What did the other book you mentioned have?  Only text?  You can try the `external` library for TikZ to pre-compile the pictures.  It will take a _really_ long time on the first run, but it _might_ improve the other ones.  You can also use `\includeonly{<file>}` to compile chapters separately.  But if you just want to build the whole thing once, I find 3 minutes a reasonable time

Comment: It didn't take 3 minutes with pdftex for me, though it was indeed a long rune (maybe 45 seconds). If the code contains lots of tikz pictures, then it takes time. Furthermore Windows is usually slower than linux.

Comment: Additionally my TeXLive pass had to generate bbm fonts  as they are only available as Type3 bitmap. I'm also getting a lot of `Missing character: There is no X in font nullfont!
` for various values of `X`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes Shelah is almost text only. BTW I was trying to `gunzip` the file from ArXive but it was not possible to do so. IT was only possible to untar it with `tar -xvf` though it is claimed that the format is source.tar.gz. So I have downloaded both, the tar.exe and gunzip.exe but the latter claims that the file is not in `.gz` format. Depsite this, the `tar.exe -xvf` works. What's wrong here (i.e. I was trying to obtain source.tar with gunziped `.tar` but this was not possbile) ?

Comment: @user2925716 Maybe `gunzip` checks the file extension (for some reason).  But the source is `.tar.gz` indeed.  And `tar` understands a gzipped file, that's why it worked

Comment: @campa Yes I have made it work with `pdflatex` and this suffices for me for now.